What is the Microsoft.Practices.Unity ResolverOverride equivalent in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
I am trying to update my dependency injection to use Microsoft's built in dependency injection rather than using the deprecated Unity dependency injection.
Unity has the following resolve: Resolve(Type t, string name, params ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides);
I was trying to do the same thing with a ServiceProvider, but there is no such function. Is there a Service Provider function that does this?
After doing some research I found that creating an instance using ActivatorUtilities could be the fix to my problem, however I need help with the object[] parameter. I need one that is similar if not exactly the same as ResolverOverride, but I no longer want to use the Unity package. Is there a class that acts exactly like this?
If not, where can I find the source code of ParameterOverride so I can make the class myself. Using Google, I could only find the Microsoft Documentation but it doesn't contain any useful information

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For those who stumble upon this post, I solved it by just making my own function.
If want to know what my function looked like:
My custom function takes in the implementation type, and a Map with the key being the parameter name and the value being the value of the parameter. The function looks through all of the constructors and picks the constructor that best matches the parameters passed in. To get the implementation type given the service type, you can use the service collection and call something like collection.FirstOrDefault(...)

There isn't an equivalent, but there are workarounds:
When you register a type like this
services.AddTransient<SomeType>();

...then when it's resolved, the ServiceProvider will also resolve its constructor parameters according to whatever has been registered.
If you want to override that you must register the type with a function that lets you specify the various parameters. Then you have more control over them.
For example,
services.AddTransient<SomeClass>(serviceProvider =>
    new SomeClass(
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWhatever>(),
        
        // this is the override. It specifies an implementation
        // that might be different from what the container
        // would resolve otherwise.
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeSpecificTypeOtherImplementation>()
    ));

As you can see, the function gives you access to the runtime ServiceProvider so that if there are types you need to resolve so you can pass them to the constructor, you can still do that.
The actual constructor parameter type might be ISomeSpecificType, and maybe a different concrete class is registered as its implementation. But now when SomeClass is created, instead of resolving the registered implementation of that interface, it will resolve the concrete type.
That assumes that you've also registered that type.
services.AddTransient<SomeSpecificTypeOtherImplementation>();

It doesn't have to be a type registered with the container. You could also do
services.AddTransient<SomeClass>(serviceProvider =>
    new SomeClass(
        serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWhatever>(),       
        new SomeSpecificTypeOtherImplementation() // not resolved
    ));

The downside is that because you're calling the class's constructor, you have to specify every argument. That's just another good reason not to have too many constructor arguments.

Option two:
Install Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection and use Unity in your application.
This is documented in the repo.
Then you can use Unity and its features. There are similar packages for Autofac and other containers that have functionality not available in the default container.

What about using ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider, Type, Object[])? Would that not be a direct replacement for Resolve?

That's best in a scenario where the type is unknown. If we can create an object by calling the class's constructor that's better.
